# Benefit of having a delete and a deleteById in the Spring Repository interfaces

Tags: spring-data-jpa, crud-repository, jparepository

I really wonder why there is a `void deleteById(ID id);` and a `void delete(T entity);` in the Spring `CrudRepository` interface.

In my code I'm working with the `JpaRepository` which extends the `CrudRepository`. The concrete implementation in Spring in this case is `SimpleJpaRepository`. If you take a look into this class, you can see, that under the hood, the `deleteById(ID id)` is calling `findById(id)` first and after that it calls `delete(T entity)`.

It seems like if I use the `delete(T entity)` the content of the object dosen't matter. I tried the following:

```
@Test
void deleteEntry() {
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setSku("ABCDE");
    product.setName("name");
    product.setDescription("description");
    product.setPrice(BigDecimal.valueOf(42l));
    product.setActive(true);
    product.setImageUrl("imageUrl");

    productRepository.save(product);
    
    // new product, only ID is set, all other fiels are empty
    Product product1Delete = new Product();
    product1Delete.setId(product.getId());

    // use the mostly empty enitity to delete the "product" entity saved before
    productRepository.delete(product1Delete);
    
    // as the database for the entity which the deleted ID
    Optional<Product> productGivenFromDb = productRepository.findById(product.getId());

    // entity isn't present in the database anymore
    Assertions.assertTrue(!productGivenFromDb.isPresent());
}
```

And, as expected after having a look into the `SimpleJpaRepository`, it's working. The content of the given entity is completely ignored exept of the ID.

***And now my problem:*** I simply don't get why there are two delete methods. Why don't we have a `deleteById(ID id);` only?
Without having a look in the implementation I would have had expected, that the whole entity is used to find the one which shall be deleted but instead, as you see, everthing except the ID is ignored.
Therefore, in this case, both functions are doing exactly the same and I can't imagine any usecase there I would have a entity to delete but no ID.

Or are there any other implementaions which are handling this two in a different way? Any historical reasons to have both? Or convenience reasons?

Can someone enlighten me please? I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the implementation of these two methods, deleteById itself uses delete. If, for example, only the id is passed to the server by the request, we use deleteById (which uses findById and delete), but if we have entity somewhere in our code, we use delete and deleteById is no longer needed.

SimpleJpaRepository:

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public void deleteById(ID id) {

        Assert.notNull(id, ID_MUST_NOT_BE_NULL);

*****It uses findById and delete(T entity)*****

        delete(findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new EmptyResultDataAccessException(
                String.format("No %s entity with id %s exists!", entityInformation.getJavaType(), id), 1)));
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository#delete(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    @Transactional
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void delete(T entity) {

        Assert.notNull(entity, "Entity must not be null!");

        if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
            return;
        }

        Class<?> type = ProxyUtils.getUserClass(entity);

        T existing = (T) em.find(type, entityInformation.getId(entity));

        // if the entity to be deleted doesn't exist, delete is a NOOP
        if (existing == null) {
            return;
        }

        em.remove(em.contains(entity) ? entity : em.merge(entity));
    }
```

Comment: That's exactly what i wrote in my initial post, because I have already looked into the implementation. I just wanted to know WHY there are both of them. ;)